# Check users subscriptions?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Is it possible to check how many subscriptions a channel has made?

I have been looking around in Youtubes API without any success.

Note: I am not looking for the amount of subscribers but the amount of subscriptions.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=ID&key=KEY
```

The above call returns for example the amount of subscribers which I don't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following request to get the subscriptions made by channel. As you need only count I'm using part=id.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=id&channelId={YOUR_CHANNEL_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Then look for the 'totalResults' attribute to get the count of subscription made by the channel